# send keystroke SHIFT+PRINTSCREEN in python

Tags: python, windows, keystroke

I want to press the keystroke SHIFT+PRINTSCREEN via python. This should trigger the last captured screenshot using Greenshot. I tried the following:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
hotkey('shift', 'PRTSC')
```

Nothing happened then I tried using AutoIT:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Auto = Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")
Auto.Send("+{PRINTSCREEN}")
```

Nothing happened. Powershell could work with this but I don't know the command for PRINTSCREEN:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{c}")
```

Is there an easier way which works?

```
SendWait("+{PRTSC}") works apparantly ...
```

Answer (score 0):

SendWait("+{PRTSC}") works apparantly ...